# Outlook selected item in advanced search

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to to run this code in the Advanced Search window. If I run it, the currExplorer.Selection remains that of the main window and not the one selected in the search window

```
        currExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer()
        For Each objItem In currExplorer.Selection
```

Comment: Is the search actually being displayed in the Explorer?

Comment: The advanced search window is in the foreground. The Explorer is in background.  I added a button in the context menu that executes operations on selected mails, but does not work with the Advanced Search window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explorer.Selection only works in the Explorer window. There is no way to access the items in the Advanced Search window.

Comment: There is no way? if i select mail in the Advanced Search window and right click, you open the context menu. You can select if delete the email, forward, categorizing, and and I added a button that should do some actions. Not really able to interact with those mails?

Comment: **Outlook** can access those items, you (through the Outlook Object Model) cannot.